# Lattice GLB uniqueness .

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

[image]

In the above lattice is the GLB of b and c unique? I think the GLB of b and c should be only d. In my book it's given that the GLB of b and c is not unique as GLB of b and c can even be a.

I think that GLB of b and c would not have been unique if d and a would have been at same level which is not the case here.

Can someone tell me whether I am right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the GLB (or $\inf$, for infimum), is the greatest lower bound. Looking at your Hasse diagram, the set $\{b,c\}$ has two lower bounds, namely $a$ and $d$. However, these two (i.e. $a$ and $d$) are not comparable, so there is no maximum among the lower bounds. Hence, the GLB of $b$ and $c$ does not exist. In particular, this tells you that your ordered set is **not** a lattice.

Comment: Why a and d are not comparable ? d is at a higher level than a in the hasse diagram right ? So it should be greater.

Comment: Higher has nothing to do with it.   There is no line between them.   The same   partial order could be diagramed with d  below a.

Comment: If there would have been a line between d and a, then they are not interchangeable right ? And d and e are not interchangeable right, as it would mean eRb rather than bRe which is not correct .Am I correct about the second statement ?@William Elliot

Comment: @Zephyr As William says, the order relation is indicated by the lines; the height at which the elements are drawn means nothing if there's no line. If there were a line joining $a$ and $d$ **and** $a$ was lower than $d$, then we would have $a\le d$, but this is not the case.

Comment: Can you tell me if my second statement about exchanging d and e is correct or not?

Comment: @Zephyr I'm not sure I understand your second statement.

Comment: @Zephyr.  No you cannot interchange d and e.  Confirm that the ordered pairs of the order R are ab, ac, db, dc, be, ce, ae, de where xy is xRy.  That is the order.  The diagram is not the order, only a picture which can change depending upon from where the photo was taked.  So use the collection of ordered pairs instead of the diagram to answer your questions.  Math is not pictures.

Comment: Yeah. I knew d and e cannot be interchanged, just confirmed it.